# Can't connect to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sequelpro

I'm trying to connect to MySQL, using Sequel Pro, something I have done many times before. Host 127.0.0.1, username root, no password. I get the following message:

Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 because access was denied.

Double-check your username and password and ensure that access from your current location is permitted.

MySQL said: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

---

For what it's worth, I got this message after upgrading to a new Mac OS (Mavericks), realized that the server wasn't running, downloaded a new server (which is currently running), and tried again - but I had the same problem.

Comment: root has most probably a password now :S

Comment: This should help: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: @CedricSimon - A textedit file with the password showed up on my desktop. I tried putting that in as the password (username still root) and it didn't work.

Comment: @japem: A text file with a password in it randomly showed up on your desktop without intervention? Does that seem likely?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL said: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48812947/mysql-said-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-no)

Comment: you can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281594/error-1698-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you are running MySql in background System Preferences -> Mysql -> Start MySql
2. Make sure you are able to connect to MySql through command line, if command line works, there is no reason why it should not work in SequelPro.
3. If problem still persists, try changing the 'root' password.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to my in Mac. I went to system preferences -> MySQL -> Stopped the server, started it again, and it worked.