# ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, iredmail

I'm setting up a new server and keep running into this problem.

When I try to log into the MySQL database with the root user, I get the error:

> ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

It doesn't matter if I connect through the terminal (SSH), through [phpMyAdmin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin) or a MySQL client, e.g., [Navicat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navicat). They all fail.

I looked in the *mysql.user* table and get the following:

```
+------------------+-------------------+
| user             | host              |
+------------------+-------------------+
| root             | %                 |
| root             | 127.0.0.1         |
| amavisd          | localhost         |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost         |
| iredadmin        | localhost         |
| iredapd          | localhost         |
| mysql.sys        | localhost         |
| phpmyadmin       | localhost         |
| root             | localhost         |
| roundcube        | localhost         |
| vmail            | localhost         |
| vmailadmin       | localhost         |
| amavisd          | test4.folkmann.it |
| iredadmin        | test4.folkmann.it |
| iredapd          | test4.folkmann.it |
| roundcube        | test4.folkmann.it |
| vmail            | test4.folkmann.it |
| vmailadmin       | test4.folkmann.it |
+------------------+-------------------+
```

As you can see, user *root* should have access.

The Server is quite simple, as I have tried to troubleshoot this for a while now.

It's running [Ubuntu 16.04.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29) LTS (Xenial Xerus) with Apache, MySQL and PHP, so that it can host websites, and iRedMail 0.9.5-1, so that it can host mail.

Log into the MySQL database works fine before I installed iRedMail. I also tried just installing iRedMail, but then root also doesn't work.

How can I fix my MySQL login problem or how can I install iRedMail over an existing MySQL install? And yes, I tried the [Installation Tips](https://code.google.com/archive/p/iredmail/wikis/Installation_Tips.wiki) and I can't find those variables in the configuration files.

Comment: I followed this link and the first option worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/questions/763336/cannot-enter-phpmyadmin-as-root-mysql-5-7

Comment: `sudo mysql_secure_installation` is easiest way to fix that

Comment: On 2022-03-02, this was *the* number one search engine hit for "`MySQL client ERROR 1698 28000 Access denied for user`".

Answer (score 1683, accepted):

On some systems, like [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29), MySQL is using the [Unix auth_socket plugin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/5.5/en/socket-pluggable-authentication.html) by default.

Basically it means that: *db_users using it, will be "authenticated" by **the system user credentials.*** You can see if your `root` user is set up like this by doing the following:

```
sudo mysql -u root # I had to use "sudo" since it was a new installation

mysql> USE mysql;
mysql> SELECT User, Host, plugin FROM mysql.user;

+------------------+-----------------------+
| User             | plugin                |
+------------------+-----------------------+
| root             | auth_socket           |
| mysql.sys        | mysql_native_password |
| debian-sys-maint | mysql_native_password |
+------------------+-----------------------+
```

As you can see in the query, the `root` user is using the `auth_socket` plugin.

There are two ways to solve this:

1. You can set the *root* user to use the `mysql_native_password` plugin
2. You can create a new `db_user` with you `system_user` (recommended)

**Option 1:**

```
sudo mysql -u root # I had to use "sudo" since it was a new installation

mysql> USE mysql;
mysql> UPDATE user SET plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> exit;

sudo service mysql restart
```

**Option 2:** (replace YOUR_SYSTEM_USER with the username you have)

```
sudo mysql -u root # I had to use "sudo" since it was a new installation

mysql> USE mysql;
mysql> CREATE USER 'YOUR_SYSTEM_USER'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'YOUR_PASSWD';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'YOUR_SYSTEM_USER'@'localhost';
mysql> UPDATE user SET plugin='auth_socket' WHERE User='YOUR_SYSTEM_USER';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> exit;

sudo service mysql restart
```

Remember that if you use option #2 you'll have to connect to MySQL as your system username (`mysql -u YOUR_SYSTEM_USER`).

**Note:** On some systems (e.g., [Debian 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Debian_9_(Stretch)) (Stretch)) the 'auth_socket' plugin is called ['unix_socket'](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/), so the corresponding SQL command should be: `UPDATE user SET plugin='unix_socket' WHERE User='YOUR_SYSTEM_USER';`

From [andy's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281594/error-1698-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost#comment92462504_42742610) it seems that MySQL 8.x.x updated/replaced the `auth_socket` for `caching_sha2_password`. I don't have a system setup with MySQL 8.x.x to test this. However, the steps above should help you to understand the issue. Here's the reply:

*One change as of MySQL 8.0.4 is that the new default authentication plugin is 'caching_sha2_password'. The new 'YOUR_SYSTEM_USER' will have this authentication plugin and you can log in from the Bash shell now with "mysql -u YOUR_SYSTEM_USER -p" and provide the password for this user on the prompt. There isn’t any need for the "UPDATE user SET plugin" step.*

*For the 8.0.4 default authentication plugin update, see* ***[MySQL 8.0.4: New Default Authentication Plugin: caching_sha2_password](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-4-new-default-authentication-plugin-caching_sha2_password/)***.

Comment: Option 1 worked for me.  But then I also needed to run `sudo gedit /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`.  Then I did a search for `AllowNoPassword` and uncommented both lines that contained it.  Then I was able to login as root with no password.

Comment: This percona blog post helped me a bit. https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/03/16/change-user-password-in-mysql-5-7-with-plugin-auth_socket/

Sounds like this happens if you try to skip setting a password for root, which then causes the 'auth_plugin' to use the unix auth_socket, which apparently just compares users.

Comment: Option 2 works. I think its always best practice to create a new user and use leaving root to be there!

Comment: the `IDENTIFIED BY ''` bit should probably be `IDENTIFIED BY 'YOUR_PASSWD'`

Comment: And that's why I prefer using PostgreSQL

Comment: Finally, an answer that *actually works* !!  There's a zillion answers out there saying do `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables` etc, and it's not been working.

Comment: It worked. However, beware that changing the plugin as per Option #1 may end up in being forced to reset the root password with 'mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables'. Then it works.

Comment: Ok, how to do this, if `sudo mysql -u root -p` doesn't let me in?

Comment: @HrvojeT can you describe a bit more the error. most of the times that could be a typo, or that for some reason the root user doesn't exist try this `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop` then
`sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &` in the mysql console type
`use mysql;` and finally `select user,host from user where user='root' \G
you might find out that for some reason the root user doesn't even exist.

Comment: @zetacu I mean how can I enter in mysql with root user if the error is `access denied` like in OP. Obviously, the solution is to create a database from start.

Comment: @Hrvoje have you tried simply `sudo mysql -u root` - since auth is not password but as the user you are accessing mysql as (i.e. root)

Comment: plugin value was initially `unix_socket` for me and otherwise all worked great - thank you

Comment: @zetacu Thanks.  This was the cause.  We fixed it in Ubuntu.  Just FYI, we tried in CentOS - it did not have this issue.  So I guess this was done at Ubuntu end - to use linux root interface instead of mysql standalone authentication.

Comment: Thanks @zetacu. How can I avoid `sudo` from `sudo mysql -u root -p` ?

Comment: @abu abu Hi Abu.  You can avoid sudo by logging into the root user before executing the command. Initially when you login you can login as 'root' or a user that has root privileges.  Else, before sudo, we can use 'sudo su', su meaning superuser before the line.  Without root we cant execute admin level commands.

Comment: Thanks for this very helpful and detailed solution. One change as of MySQL 8.0.4 is that the new default authentication plugin is 'caching_sha2_password'. The new  'YOUR_SYSTEM_USER' will have this auth plugin and you can login from the bash shell now with "mysql -u YOUR_SYSTEM_USER -p" and provide the password for this user on the prompt. No need for the "UPDATE user SET plugin" step. For the 8.0.4 default auth plugin update see, https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-4-new-default-authentication-plugin-caching_sha2_password/

Comment: The first option worked for me. Thanks! 
Although, if I am not wrong after performing the second option, the first option has to be done on the YOUR_SYSTEM_USER i.e., change the plugin of newly made user to mysql_native_password. 

OR

The plugin can be set as 'mysql_native_password' while performing the second option in this line 

`mysql> UPDATE user SET plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='YOUR_SYSTEM_USER';
` 

What do you think?

Comment: the second option is meant to use the "new" (not new anymore) `auth_socket` (or any other name on each system) plugin you can for sure mix it and instead of using the `auth_socket` you can change it to use the `mysql_native_password `, if you do that then you'll have to use the mysql password that can be different from the system password.

Comment: If using MariaDB, use the steps here instead -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/57532576/69739

Comment: You can do user and plugin in one line: CREATE USER 'YOUR_SYSTEM_USER'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH auth_socket;

Comment: When `UPDATE user`, I met `ERROR 1348 (HY000): Column 'plugin' is not updatable`.

Comment: Yes, use `sudo mysql -uroot` after install mariadb 10.5.9 in fedora-34 workstation from fedora repositories.

Comment: The link is (effectively) broken: *"Page Not Found. We're sorry, but the requested post could not be found."*

Comment: Worked for MariaDB, version 10.3 on Ubuntu 20.04 as well.

Comment: For my local dev environment, a simple password-less root account is all I need, so switching the authentication plugin to `mysql_native_password` fixed the issue for me. Thanks!

Comment: I logged in just to say, "Thank You!" Your answer resolved my days-long log-in issue. You -- are my HERO!

Answer (score 363):

#### A *new* version of MySQL does it this way

In the new MySQL client, if the password is left empty while installing then, it is based on the `auth_socket` plugin.

The correct way is to log in to MySQL with the `sudo` privilege.

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

And then updating the password using:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'new-password';
```

Once this is done, *stop and start* the MySQL server.

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo service mysql start
```

For complete details, you can refer to [this link](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/03/16/change-user-password-in-mysql-5-7-with-plugin-auth_socket/).

Comment: That worked for my dev server as a quick fix (Ubuntu 18.04 server), however, I do recommend looking into the above-accepted answer, and furthermore, refrain from installing PHPMyAdmin on a production server altogether.

Comment: "-p" is not necessary when using "sudo"

Comment: wow, this worked for me, mysql  Ver 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, #nitipSendal

Comment: @AaronMurray I'm not currently doing it but I'm curious, why is PHPMyAdmin not suitable for production and what would you use as a GUI instead? Or are you saying production servers should have no GUIs?

Comment: @HashimAziz It is not that PHPMyAdmin is not suitable for production, I am suggesting merely (in my opinion), database server access should be a service that is hidden from public access.  Of course it depends on use case, but by default I keep my public exposure to any infrastructure at a minimum.  Meaning say your web server accessible public on port 80/443, but the PHP app itself would access an internal (private network) database, not exposed to the public.  Doesn't prevent attacks but is a single step towards better security.  ** Use cases may differ and require public facing IP's **

Comment: I get `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'BY 'root'' at line 1`

Comment: For newer MySQL versions use this syntax instead: `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';`

Answer (score 34):

No need of sudo

The database is initialised with 2 all-privilege accounts: the first one is "root" which is inaccessible and the second one with your user name (check with command `whoami`).

To enable access to root account, you need to login with your user name

```
mysql -u $(whoami)
```

and manually change password for root

```
use mysql;
set password for 'root'@'localhost' = password('YOUR_ROOT_PASSWORD_HERE');
flush privileges;
quit
```

Login as 'root'

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Comment: when i use  `mysql -u $(whoami)` , also it gives `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'kaw'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Comment: set password for 'root'@'localhost' = password('YOUR_ROOT_PASSWORD_HERE');
This saved my day

Comment: This looks promising, but I don't think this works at all (like  
[Kaumadie Kariyawasam mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281594/error-1698-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost#comment118733540_59687197)). What system, incl. version of the operating system, MySQL, etc. was this tried on? What state was the system in, e.g. wrt. to permissions, users, groups, etc.?

Comment: I definitely needed `sudo`. I had to open mysql like this `sudo mysql` first then I executed your commands and the password is changed now

Answer (score 14):

I was having this issue on an [Debian 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Debian_8_(Jessie)) (Jessie) VM that I was interacting with through [PuTTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY) on my Windows 10 desktop.

I tried the various suggestions on here, but nothing quite worked and I am running [MariaDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MariaDB) on the Debian host.  In the end I found that I couldn't start the database server in safe mode, but I didn't need to and the following commands actually worked for me, i.e., allowing a newly created MySQL user to log into the MySQL/MariaDB server:

```
sudo service mysql restart
sudo mysql # Logs in automatically into MariaDB
use mysql;
update user set plugin='' where user='your_user_name';
flush privileges;
exit;
sudo service mysql restart # Restarts the MySQL service
```

If the above doesn't quite work for you, follow the steps outlined in [zetacu's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42742610/4826364), and then follow my steps.

Now you should be able to use a remote terminal client and securely log into MySQL using the command:

```
mysql -u your_user_name -p
```

*Type in the password when prompted

Comment: That simple. Well, only first command does not allowed to execute the second, so I'll adjust it editing - please see if I'm right...

Comment: `update user set plugin='' where user='your_user_name';` Did worked for me

Answer (score 14):

Step 1. `sudo mysql -u root -p`

Step 2. `USE mysql;`

Step 3. `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'admin';`

Here 'admin' is your new password, but you can change it.

Step 4. `exit`

You are done.

Answer (score 9):

After hours of struggling without any solution here, this worked for me. I found [a YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sG5Z4JqhRx8) video where it says the password column is now called *authentication_string*.

So I was able to change my password as follows:

First get into the MySQL client from the terminal:

```
sudo mysql
```

Then inside *mysql*, type whatever after `mysql>`:

```
mysql> use mysql
mysql> update user set authentication_string=PASSWORD("mypass") where user='root';
mysql> flush privileges;
mysql> quit;
```

At this point you are out of the MySQL client, back to your normal terminal place. You need to restart the MySQL client for this to take effect. For that type, the following:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Refer to [this video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sG5Z4JqhRx8) for a better understanding.

Comment: I used your second command, I got this: 
```ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '("jovialp") where user='root'' at line 1 ```

Answer (score 9):

There is a good and regularly updated guide on how to set a new password for the latest MySQL:

*[How To Install MySQL on Ubuntu 20.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-20-04)*

It would be best to read the whole topic from the above page, but in short, this maybe could help.

Run the security script:

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

[Detailed information for `mysql_secure_installation`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-20-04#step-2-configuring-mysql)

After that, you can change the password by following the next steps:

```
sudo mysql
```

> mysql> `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'password';`

[Detailed information for changing the root user password](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-20-04#step-3-%E2%80%94-optional-adjusting-user-authentication-and-privileges)

If you have a problem, maybe you will need to reinstall MySQL.

Comment: I type sudo mysql_secure_installation , it asked me enter new password for mysql( ubuntu 20.0 server version)

Comment: this work for me , thanks . on ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest to remove the MySQL connection -

This is for MySQL version 5.5. If your version is different, please change the first line accordingly.

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-server-core-5.5 mysql-client-core-5.5
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

And install again, but this time set a root password yourself.
This will save a lot of effort.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Comment: @ingernet maybe thats because of some other issues which you neglected while installing again

Comment: @PJBrunet  maybe cause your version of Mysql is different

Comment: Fair enough, but an all-purpose solution is best.

Comment: What do you mean by *"remove the MySQL connection"*? Remove the installation and remove configuration files?

Answer (score 7):

For the first

```
sudo mysql -u root -p

SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'validate_password%';
```

we will see something like this:

```
+--------------------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name                        | Value  |
+--------------------------------------+--------+
| validate_password.check_user_name    | ON     |
| validate_password.dictionary_file    |        |
| validate_password.length             | 8      |
| validate_password.mixed_case_count   | 1      |
| validate_password.number_count       | 1      |
| validate_password.policy             | MEDIUM |
| validate_password.special_char_count | 1      |
+--------------------------------------+--------+
```

We need to change these rows:

> 1. validate_password.length
> 2. validate_password.number_count
> 3. validate_password.policy
> 4. validate_password.special_char_count

```
SET GLOBAL validate_password.policy=LOW;
SET GLOBAL validate_password.length=4;
SET GLOBAL validate_password.number_count=0;
SET GLOBAL validate_password.special_char_count=0;

SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'validate_password%';
```

We will see:

```
+--------------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                        | Value |
+--------------------------------------+-------+
| validate_password.check_user_name    | ON    |
| validate_password.dictionary_file    |       |
| validate_password.length             | 4     |
| validate_password.mixed_case_count   | 1     |
| validate_password.number_count       | 0     |
| validate_password.policy             | LOW   |
| validate_password.special_char_count | 0     |
+--------------------------------------+-------+
```

Now exit from the MySQL client:

```
exit;
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

And now you can write your password, four or more only letters.

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'new-password';

exit;

sudo mysql -u root -p
```

Your new password is in the database for user 'root';

Answer (score 6):

I also faced the same issue for the first time.

Now it is fixed:

First, you copy the `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` file and paste in to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`.

You can do it by the command:

```
sudo cp /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Now let's reset the password:

Use the following commands in your terminal:

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo service mysql start
sudo mysql -u root
```

Now you are inside the MySQL console.

Then let's write some queries to reset our root password:

```
USE mysql
update mysql.user set authentication_string=password('newpass') where user='root' and Host ='localhost';
update user set plugin="mysql_native_password";
flush privileges;
quit
```

Now we can clean `/etc/mysql/my.cng`.

Open the above file in your editor and remove the whole lines inside the file.

After that let's restart MySQL:

```
sudo mysql service restart
```

Now let's use MySQL with the newly created password:

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

Finally enter your newly created password.

Comment: Worked Well ! but your answer needs to be updated !! /etc/mysql/my.cnf and not /etc/mysql/my.cng and for service restart its sudo service mysql restart

Answer (score 6):

I found my solution after hours of research here.

**Stop MySQL**

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

**Make MySQL service directory.**

```
sudo mkdir /var/run/mysqld
```

**Give MySQL user permission to write to the service directory.**

```
sudo chown mysql: /var/run/mysqld
```

**Start MySQL manually, without permission checks or networking.**

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
```

**Log in without a password.**

```
mysql -uroot mysql
```

**Update password**

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('YOURNEWPASSWORD'), plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root' AND Host='%';
EXIT;
```

**Turn off MySQL.**

```
sudo mysqladmin -S /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock shutdown
```

**Start the MySQL service normally.**

```
sudo service mysql start
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case,

```
mysql -u root -p

Enter password:
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

I am sure my password was correct. Otherwise, the error code would be `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user`

So I relogin using *sudo*,

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

This time it worked for me. See [the documentation](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-18-04).

And then change the root password,

```
mysql> alter user 'root'@'%' identified with mysql_native_password by 'me123';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.14 sec)

mysql>
```

Then restart the server using `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`.

Answer (score 4):

[This](https://askubuntu.com/a/763359/521999) worked for me:

```
mysql --user=root mysql
CREATE USER 'some_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'some_user'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Even with the link, an explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist, e.g. for the first line? Why didn't the previous answers work? What version of MySQL was used? On what system? In what context? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53981513/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: You are right @PeterMortensen. I don't know why I posted it at first place. It seems pretty the same as zetacu second option. Please let me know that you read my comment and then I'll just delete my answer.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me with MySQL version 8.0.26 and [Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) (Focal Fossa).

```sh
sudo mysql -u root

mysql> USE mysql;
mysql> SELECT User, Host, plugin FROM mysql.user;

+------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| User             | Host      | plugin                |
+------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| debian-sys-maint | localhost | caching_sha2_password |
| mysql.infoschema | localhost | caching_sha2_password |
| mysql.session    | localhost | caching_sha2_password |
| mysql.sys        | localhost | caching_sha2_password |
| root             | localhost | auth_socket           |
+------------------+-----------+-----------------------+

mysql> UPDATE user SET

plugin='caching_sha2_password' WHERE User='root';

mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'you_mysql_password';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> exit;

sudo service mysql restart
```

Comment: This worked for me - I forgot the login method needs to change from auth socket to password. Periodically I find it changes itself back, not sure why.

Answer (score 3):

First step: go to file */etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php*, and then uncomment lines where you find *"AllowNoPassword"*.

Second step: log in to your MySQL default account

```
mysql -u root -p

use mysql;
update user set plugin="" where user='root';
flush privileges;
```

And that's all!

Comment: What are the presumptions? That [phpMyAdmin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin) is already installed? What context was this tried in? What operating system/distribution/version? Cloud? [VPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server)? Own server? Own workstation? What was installed? For example, folder `/etc/phpmyadmin` ***doesn't exist*** by default on desktop [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver), even after Apache, PHP, and MariaDB have been installed.

Comment: Please respond by [editing (changing) your question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49886515/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 3):

OS: [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver)

MySQL: 5.7

1. Add the `skip-grant-tables` to the end of file *mysqld.cnf*
2. Copy the *my.cnf* file

   ```
   sudo cp /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf
   ```
3. Reset the password

   ```
   (base) ➜  ~ sudo service mysql stop
   (base) ➜  ~ sudo service mysql start
   (base) ➜  ~ mysql -uroot
   Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
   Your MySQL connection id is 2
   Server version: 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 (Ubuntu)

   Copyright (c) 2000, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

   Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
   affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
   owners.

   Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

   mysql> use mysql
   Reading table information for completion of table and column names
   You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

   Database changed, 3 warnings
   mysql> update mysql.user set authentication_string=password('newpass') where user='root' and Host ='localhost';
   Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
   Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 1

   mysql> update user set plugin="mysql_native_password";
   Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
   Rows matched: 4  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

   mysql>  flush privileges;
   Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

   mysql> quit
   Bye
   ```
4. Remove the `skip-grant-tables` from my.cnf

   ```
   (base) ➜  ~ sudo emacs /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
   (base) ➜  ~ sudo emacs /etc/mysql/my.cnf
   (base) ➜  ~ sudo service mysql restart
   ```
5. Open the MySQL client

   ```
   (base) ➜  ~ mysql -uroot -ppassword
   mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
   Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
   Your MySQL connection id is 3
   Server version: 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 (Ubuntu)

   Copyright (c) 2000, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

   Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
   affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
   owners.

   Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

   mysql>
   ```
6. Check the password policy

   ```
   mysql> select @@validate_password_policy;
   +----------------------------+
   | @@validate_password_policy |
   +----------------------------+
   | MEDIUM                     |
   +----------------------------+
   1 row in set (0.00 sec)


   mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'validate_password%';
   +--------------------------------------+--------+
   | Variable_name                        | Value  |
   +--------------------------------------+--------+
   | validate_password_dictionary_file    |        |
   | validate_password_length             | 8      |
   | validate_password_mixed_case_count   | 1      |
   | validate_password_number_count       | 1      |
   | validate_password_policy             | MEDIUM |
   | validate_password_special_char_count | 1      |
   +--------------------------------------+--------+
   6 rows in set (0.08 sec)！
   ```
7. Change the configuration of the `validate_password`

   ```
   mysql> set global validate_password_policy=0;
   Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

   mysql> set global validate_password_mixed_case_count=0;
   Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

   mysql> set global validate_password_number_count=3;
   Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

   mysql> set global validate_password_special_char_count=0;
   Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

   mysql> set global validate_password_length=3;
   Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

   mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'validate_password%';
   +--------------------------------------+-------+
   | Variable_name                        | Value |
   +--------------------------------------+-------+
   | validate_password_dictionary_file    |       |
   | validate_password_length             | 3     |
   | validate_password_mixed_case_count   | 0     |
   | validate_password_number_count       | 3     |
   | validate_password_policy             | LOW   |
   | validate_password_special_char_count | 0     |
   +--------------------------------------+-------+
   6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
   ```

#### Note

You should know that you error caused by what? validate_password_policy?

You should have decided to reset the your password to fill the policy or change the policy.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me on mysql Ver 15.1:

```
$ sudo mysql

MariaDB [mysql]> use mysql;
MariaDB [mysql]> set password for 'root'@'localhost' = password('YOUR_ROOT_PASSWORD_HERE');
MariaDB [mysql]> flush privileges;
MariaDB [mysql]> quit
```

Login as 'root'

```
mysql -u root -p
```

---

Credits to [Raoul HATTERER](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5952631/raoul-hatterer)

Answer (score 3):

the answer given by @zetacu and @peter is very accurate but only part of it worked for me. Adding this here for users who are using

```
mysql  Ver 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

So, my user table looked like this:

```
mysql> SELECT User,Host,plugin FROM mysql.user;
+------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| User             | Host      | plugin                |
+------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| debian-sys-maint | localhost | caching_sha2_password |
| mysql.infoschema | localhost | caching_sha2_password |
| mysql.session    | localhost | caching_sha2_password |
| mysql.sys        | localhost | caching_sha2_password |
| pk               | localhost | auth_socket           |
| root             | localhost | auth_socket           |
+------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So, first I followed the second(recommended) option of replacing YOUR_SYSTEM_USER with the username you have. So, I created a new user with same approach but nothing worked.

Then I tried the first approach to set root user to use my_native_password plugin:

```
sudo mysql -u root
mysql> USE MySQL;
mysql> UPDATE user SET plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE 
User='root';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> exit;

sudo service mysql restart
```

AND IT WORKED!!! SO, just create a new user and make it use my_native_password plugin.

Answer (score 1):

For those installing the latest MariaDB on macOS and following [this tutorial](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/installing-mariadb-10-1-16-on-mac-os-x-with-homebrew/) in MariaDB's documentation, run:

`sudo mariadb-secure-installation`

instead of just the `mariadb-secure-installation` command given. Otherwise, no luck, despite the erroneous prompt:

```
In order to log into MariaDB to secure it, we'll need the current
password for the root user. If you've just installed MariaDB, and
haven't set the root password yet, you should just press enter here.

Enter current password for root (enter for none):
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
Enter current password for root (enter for none):
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
Enter current password for root (enter for none):
Aborting!
```

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me as well. The problem is with the MySQL repository that comes already with the Linux distribution. So when you simply do:

```
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

It installs MySQL from their default repository which gives this problem. So to overcome that you need to uninstall that installed MySQL:

```
sudo apt remove mysql* --purge --auto-remove
```

Then download the MySQL repository from official MySQL website [MySQL APT repository](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/).

Follow their documentation on how to add a repository and
install it. This gives no issue.

Also as [answered by zetacu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281594/error-1698-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost/42742610#42742610), you can verify that the MySQL *root* user now indeed uses the mysql_native_password plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the following steps to get rid of this issue.

Log in into the MySQL in your machine using (**sudo mysql -p -u root**) and hit the following queries.

1. CREATE USER 'jack'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '<>';
2. GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'jack'@'localhost';
3. SELECT user,plugin,host FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 'root';

   ```
   +------+-------------+-----------+
   | user | plugin      | host      |
   +------+-------------+-----------+
   | root | auth_socket | localhost |
   +------+-------------+-----------+
   ```
4. ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '<>';
5. FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Please try it once if you are still getting the error. I hope this code will help you a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that tried the solution here and nothing works, make sure you are using the correct command, sudo `sudo mysql -u root -p` and not `mysql mysql -u root -p`.

You'll need to enter two passwords, the one of the current user and the root one.

Comment: It is indeed confusing. Is it a system user name or a MySQL user name (or they may be connected somehow)? Can you make it clearer in *[your](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67629878/edit)* answer? E.g., what does "the root one" refer to? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score -1):

You want to access MySQL with root user but you're not providing root's correct password.

If you need to **set a new password for root**, MySQL's site has great documentation on how to do it: *[B.3.3.2 How to Reset the Root Password](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html)*

I'll **not** show the process in here, because MySQL's documentation on the above link is clear and concise.

Comment: Thanks for the anwser, but I couldn't get it to work, so I have chosen to install iRedMail with a pgSQL database instead.

Comment: Roger Folkman!
Good to know that you solved your problem any how.

Comment: Links break. mysql.com has had many broken links over the years. You should copy and paste the relevant information here, which is fine as long you attribute the source.