# MySQL: django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1698, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'") with correct username and pw

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-3.x, django-settings

I have `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1698, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'")` when using mysql. The username and pw are correct:

```
DB_HOST = '127.0.0.1'
DB_USER = 'root'
DB_PASSWORD = ''
```

I can log into mysql as root:

```
$ sudo mysql -u root
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 16
```

But not as `cchilders`:

```
$ mysql -u root
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

This may contribute to the problem. Last time I installed mysql this didn't happen, so it doesn't make sense to me. I have the client fine:

```
$ pip3 freeze
Django==1.10.5
mysqlclient==1.3.9
```

How can I allow MySQL to be run by my normal user, so I can run Django in the terminal?

### Update

Dirty solution:

Without any fixes, always run mysql as `sudo`

Comment: I don't know if this is the right answer, but I recently had the same problem and this worked for me: http://askubuntu.com/questions/766334/cant-login-as-mysql-user-root-from-normal-user-account-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: This one has also helped me : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281594/error-1698-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason that you can login as `root` on your server is that you probably have specified a password in the `.my.cnf` file in `/root` (i.e., the `root` user's home directory).  Check to see if there is a password there and use that for `cchilders` as well.  You can then create a django-specific application user to make sure that the django app only reads/writes/etc. to the databases that it needs access to and not access through the `root` mysql user.

```
create user 'django'@'localhost' identified by 'django-user-password';
grant usage on *.* to 'django'@'localhost';
grant all privileges on django-database-1.* to 'django'@'localhost';
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a non-root SQL user and change the DB_USER variable in the settings.py file of Django