# What does mysql -u root -p do?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to figure out what the `mysql -u root -p` command does.

I have googled the command but I can't find any good results.

Comment: -p is used to enter password..

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connecting.html

Comment: It's simply the way to execute the mysql `command` as the root user `-u root`, prompting for password `-p`.

Comment: *"I have googled the command but I can't find any good results"* - [Really?...](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+-u+root+-p) Google input text: "mysql -u root -p".

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner, this is the first result that comes up. Thanks for being helpful!

Comment: Check: [ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281594/error-1698-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost)

Answer (score 8):

`mysql -u root -p` means, that you trying to connect to MySQL shell with parameters - `-u` parameter specified MySQL user name.

> -u, --user=name     User for login if not current user.

In your case it's `root` user.

> -p, --password[=name] 
>                         Password to use when connecting to server. If password is
>                         not given it's asked from the tty.

You can type `mysql --help` from the command line for more information about all available parameters.

Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

It logs you into mysql as the root user. After -p (Immediately after it incidentally, no spaces) you would include the password.

Answer (score 2):

```
`mysql -u root -p`
```

Its initiate a connection of `MySQL`.

`-u` means that we are going to connect with a username `root`

`-p` means that we will enter username's password

Answer (score 0):

Check [man mysql](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mysql)

Your command tries to connect to MySQL on localhost with user "root" and asking for a password