# Couldn't connect mysql database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

When I try to run mysql database using following command without password

```
mysql -u root -p
```

It says following error

> ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

But I can connect database using this command without password

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

But if I try to connect database using php I am getting the same error messages saying

> ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

How should I solve this problem?

PHP code for connecting with database is

```
<?php

/* Attempt MySQL server connection.

server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","dbName");



// Check connection

if($link === false){

    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());

}



// Print host information

echo "Connect Successfully. Host info: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link);

?>
```

I got solution from stack overflow and did the same as it suggested but it didn't work for me. The link which suggested the answer is
[This link has similar question related to me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281594/error-1698-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost)

Comment: Do you type a password when connecting via terminal?

Comment: You may have set a root password, try changing it to something you know. You also have an extra quote in `""dbName"`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281594/error-1698-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost

Comment: No i didn't have password while connecting via terminal.

Comment: @Quentin, i don't know whether you read the question carefully or not before marking it duplicate, but i already tried those solutions but wasn't successful. Although i got the solution.