# ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' while installing phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, ubuntu-18.04

I tried to reconfigure phpmyadmin by this

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
```

Then after few steps I get this:

ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost'

A config file is missing (and probably more)

I'm using ubuntu 18.04

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42742610/111036) and also the comments or other answers in that page about the phpmyadmin-specific config to change.

Answer (score 1):

sudo mysql -u root -p

Next, check which authentication method each of your MySQL user accounts use with the following command:

SELECT user,plugin,host FROM mysql.user;

What is there in plugin column for 'debian-sys-maint'?

To exit the MySQL shell:

quit

Comment: How does this help solve the problem?