# OperationalError at /admin/login/ (1698, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'")

Tags: python, mysql, django

Yes, this is a common question in Stack Overflow but my problem is kinda **different!**

I have a server on **Digital Ocean**. **Os: Ubuntu 18.04**

I was trying to host my **django** project on the **apache server** with **mysql**.

I have completed the first part but the problem is integrating the **mysql**. I have installed the **mysql** and **mysqlclient**. There is a user **root** with password in my **mysql**. I have created a database and gave the following permission.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON urp_test.* TO 'root'@'localhost' identified by 'password_for_root';
```

The I configured my **settings.py** file. Here is the **db** portion:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'urp_test',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'password_for_the_db',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

Then I did a `python manage.py makemigrations`, `python manage.py migrate`, `python manage.py createsuperuser`.

All of them were executed successfully. So when I go login from the **admin** module, I see the error:

> OperationalError at /admin/login/  (1698, "Access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost'")

I tried deleting the database and doing the same thing a couple of times but the same problem.

**Edit**:

If I log in with the same user and password from **terminal**, i.e. like this:

`mysql -u root -p` with the password, I can access the databases.

As I mentioned earlier, `python manage.py createsuperuser` does create a user and I can get the user from the database table.

The problem is when I try to log in that user from the `admin` part from the browser i.e. like this:

`W.X.Y.Z:80/admin/login`

I got the mentioned error. Here `W.X.Y.Z` is the **IP** for my **DigitalOcean** server

So, it's definitely a permission error still, isn't it?

1. How can I resolve this error?
2. And also I planned to develop a sign-up module for my normal user.
   If they sign up, will this permission be accessible to them?
   Do they get any access to the database?

Comment: Did you try using command line to get into mysql with same username and password?

Comment: Yes, I did and it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some complications to opening a `db` under `root` user. You can see details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281594/error-1698-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost/42742610#42742610)

What I did:

1. logged in as root user in mysql

   `mysql> mysql -u root -p`
2. created a new user

   `mysql> CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`
3. `mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'newuser'@'localhost';`
4. `mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
5. `mysql> exit`
6. Then I logged in as new user

   `mysql -u newuser -p`

and entered the new `password` I set up earlier to create this user.

7. Then I created the `db` by

   `create database my_database_name`

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and I just change my host from 127.0.0.1 to localhost in the settings.py and is now working perfectly fine on my vps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).