# Fail to Access only on Workbench (6.3.6 Build 517 CE(64 bits) Community)

Tags: mysql, linux, mysql-workbench

I apologise.. I know this question has been asked many times before, but I've tried lots of suggestions, and simply can't find a solution.

The problem is when I try to connect on Workbench, I get the error:

> "Failed to Connect to MySQL at 127.0.0.1:3306 with user root"

But if I run `shell> mysqladmin version`, I get:

```
mysqladmin Ver 8.42 Distrib 5.7.19, for Linux on x86_64 
Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved. 

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its 
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective 
owners. 

Server version  5.7.19 
Protocol version    10 
Connection  Localhost via UNIX socket 
UNIX socket /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock 
Uptime: 32 sec 

Threads: 1 Questions: 3 Slow queries: 0 Opens: 107 Flush tables: 1 Open 
tables: 26 Queries per second avg: 0.093
```

Also the following commands runs fine:

```
shell> mysqld (service is running)

shell> mysql (login on Server)
```

The settings of "newConnection" on WB are:

```
Connection Method: Standard (TCP/IP)

Parameters.Hostname: 127.0.0.1 - Port: 3306

Parameters.Username: root

... (next values are by Default)
```

My System is **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions.

Comment: Is networking enabled for your server? MySQL Workbench tries to connect using TCP/IP, while the terminal automatically switched to sockets.

Comment: That is the question!. I changed the configuration from MySQL.Server to **mysql_native_password** (for that user) on **[user].[plugin] value** and login fine from WB. It's Works! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the configuration from MySQL.Server to **mysql_native_password** (for that user) on **[user].[plugin] value** and login fine from WB. It's Works!

This [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42742610/8484285), solve my problem.