# Not Able to Connect to MariaDB Docker Container using IntelliJ

Tags: docker, intellij-idea, connection, mariadb

I have created a Docker container using the following command:

```
docker run --network host --name mariadb -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=testpass -d mariadb:latest
```

I'm trying to connect to the MariaDB Docker container in my IntelliJ project and getting the following error:

```
The specified database user/password combination is rejected:
[28000][1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES)
```

When I run without `--network host` and use container's IP `172.18.0.2`, I get the following error:

```
[08][-1] Could not connect to address=(host=172.18.0.2)(port=3306)(type=master) : connect timed out
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out.
```

I even tried updating bind-address in `my.cnf` file in the container but no success.

Please help me.

Comment: Check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281594/error-1698-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost

Comment: better to verify the connection first inside container `docker exec -it mariadb bash -c " mysql -u root -ptestpass"`