# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS can not login to mysql using terminal ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, database, terminal, operating-system, ubuntu-18.04

I have installed ubuntu 18.04 LTS and installed mysql server. But it does not allow me to logging as root.

I have tried {mysql -u root}

but it gives

> ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

can someone help me to resolve this.

Comment: There should be a temporary password created for the initial root login. It may be in /var/log/mysqld.log

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281594/error-1698-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost)