# Mysql 8.0 password doesn't want to change but doesn't error

Tags: mysql

I've followed the procedure on [the official website](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html) but when I try going on a non root account and try logging in it simply rejects me with Error 1698, access denied. When I do the same on root any password works.

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281594/error-1698-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost?

Comment: Oh yeah, that was it