# Unable to connect to MySQL server from Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am attempting to connect MySQL server to MySQL Workbench but receive the following error:

[image: workbench]

I believe I have my server running, when I run 'mysqld --console' in 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin', I receive the following output:

[image: commandline]

The last line seems to indicate that it is listening on the correct port... but I am also not unconvinced that my server is even starting properly. Shouldn't I be able to access MySQL from the terminal one the server starts?

Comment: look intp the mysql error log and see what error shows

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281594/error-1698-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost)

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular this error seems similar but I do not even make it to the point where I am able to query the mysql.user table.