# Cannot grant any privileges to root on MySQL (problem related to auth_socket plugin)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I'm having a tough time getting up and running with MySQL on Ubuntu, and all similar questions have solutions which seem to assume that I've already solved the problem.

I installed MySQL with: `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`, then tried to configure with `sudo mysql_secure_installation`. However, output to was as follows:

```
$ sudo mysql_secure_installation

Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Connecting to MySQL using a blank password.
The user provided does not have enough permissions to continue.
mysql_secure_installation is exiting.
```

It seems this is because MySQL on Ubuntu is configured to use the auth_socket plugin. For example, see the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281594/error-1698-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost/42742610#42742610). The solutions proposed are to either:

1. Set the root user to use the mysql_native_password plugin
2. Create a new db_user with you system_user (recommended)

I am unable to do either. When I attempt them, I cannot enter the first command (nor any subsequent to it). Output is:

```
$ sudo mysql -u root # I had to use "sudo" since it was new installation

mysql> USE mysql;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'mysql'
```

When I attempt to trace down a solution to this, it seems I need to add privileges. When I attempt to do so with the following command, again I receive an errror:

```
$ sudo mysql -u root
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '';
ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the CREATE USER privilege(s) for this operation
```

I get similar error messages about privileges whenever I attempt to execute any command.

What am I missing? I am able to confirm that I am root:

```
mysql> select user(); select current_user();
+----------------+
| user()         |
+----------------+
| root@localhost |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+----------------+
| current_user() |
+----------------+
| root@localhost |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Privileges for root are as follows:

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost';
+------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                |
+------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `root`@`localhost` |
+------------------------------------------+
```

**EDIT:** I uninstalled MySQL and installed MariaDB instead and everything is working now. For the record: I was using Ubuntu 21.04 and installing `mysql-server` from the Ubuntu repositories. MariaDB, also installed from the repos, is working fine.

Comment: with sudo you have admin rights already and can change what ever you need

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? I can't execute a single command, as they all throw the `Access denied` error above.

Comment: run only `sudo mysql`

Comment: @nbk, when I do so, I get the same errors. For instance, `USE mysql;` still throws `ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'mysql'`.

Comment: it something is very wrong remove mysql completely see if all uodates are installed and start from the front

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled several times and it made no difference. However, when I switched to the MariaDB install, everything worked as expected, so I'm going to chalk this up to some issue with dependencies or the Ubuntu repos.

Comment: you can post a error report with oracle