# when i am running my flask app this error is been shown to me, how to solve this error?

Tags: python, mysql

```
mydb= mysql.connector.connect(
   host="localhost",
   user="root",
   password="",
   database="hosp_checkin"
)
```

```
1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What are you using for authentication to the database? How is the database configured? You are supplying an empty password, but the error message says that a password was not used.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42742610/1219295) help?

Comment: @RolandSmith yess tysm