# MySQL said: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

Tags: mysql, sequelpro

I am trying to create a database with Sequel Pro and it keeps coming up with an error "Unable to connect to host because access was denied.

Double-check your username and password and ensure that access from your current location is permitted.

MySQL said: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

I have mySQL server running on my Mac.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you logging in with a password in Sequel Pro? Looks like the password field is empty. If this is MAMP, use `root` as password also.

Comment: Now MySQL Server won't start!

Comment: No I am not using MAMP.

Comment: You must have then set a root password during the MySQL server setup, use that when logging in. I'd need to know the install method to help any further.

Comment: I have tried that and it says "MySQL said: Your password has expired. To log in you must change it using a client that supports expired passwords."

Comment: Not sure what to do now!

Comment: Can I uninstall MySQL and install again?

Comment: Manage to reset it using this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33387879/mysql-password-expired-cant-connect .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Newer versions of MySQL use a temporary password after setup, and you can use mysqladmin to set it to something permanent.

```
mysqladmin -u root -p password
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me discover that a randomly generated password I had set for MySQL with MAMP Pro had a character that wasn't getting escaped. While MySQL might have no password character restrictions, not all passwords can be typed right into Terminal. See also https://superuser.com/questions/1002803/mysql-password-restrictions